# jquery .data not behaving as I understand it

Tags: jquery

I have the following statement in a jQuery function, which executes when a button is pressed. It does as expected, because I immediately show the value of "dateAndTime" in an alert:

```
$("#Button1").click(function (evt) { // automatically bind the click event
    evt.preventDefault();
    var loc = window.location.href;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: loc + "/GetDate",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#Label1").text(msg.d);
            $("#Label1").data("dateAndTime", msg.d);

            alert("the date and time is " + $("#Label1").data("dateAndTime"));
        }
    });
});
```

The button, from the aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
```

The Button3_Click is an empty method.

It is my understanding that this value will be available as long as the browser window remains open. After the function that is called finishes and the page loads, I press a button which causes a postback. I have the following statement in the same .js file, in the "ready" function:

```
alert("the new date and time is " + $("#Label1").data("dateAndTime"));
```

I would expect the value originally saved would be shown, but I get "undefined" instead. Should I get what I expect, or do I not understand .data?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please? Especially the postback part.

Comment: Postback reloads the page, if the page is reloaded, than DOM  will change, therefore you wouldn't expect to get that value.

Comment: @j08691, I added more code. I understand about postbacks, but I thought the whole idea of .data was to keep data so it could be used again, without having to get it a second time.

Comment: The data is stored "on" the element, so as long as the exact same element is available, so is the data. If you replace the element or reload the page, the data is lost -> http://jsfiddle.net/KekDX/3/

Comment: Data does work, Just like you want - http://jsfiddle.net/9U9qz/1/ - There must be something else wrong with your code, what does msg contain?

Comment: In other words, "It is my understanding that this value will be available as long as the browser window remains open" is false.

Comment: msg contains DateTime.Now.ToString() from the C# code behind method. It's correct, because as I said, I show it in an alert.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to make sure your msg object has a "d" attribute. If you console.log or alert it you should see the object as { d: 'dd-MM-yyyy' };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you do a postpack the page is refreshed and all data is lost. You get a completely new document.

I would suggest you persist the data in a cookie or the sessionstorage.

Comment: Works as I expect here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_misc_data_set_get. I just don't get it...